# How to set User Defined field in Google Analytics (gtag.js, analytics.js) filter?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters, analytics.js, gtag.js

In `Google Analytics` `filters`, it is possible to leverage a `User Defined` variable:

[image]

However, I cannot find any reference or documentation which specifically states how to set the *User Defined* variable nor do I understand if the value for *Filter Pattern* field should include the *User Defined* value or both the variable name and its value.

I'd like to understand the process for setting this *User Defined* variable with `gtag.js` and `analytics.js`. Can I set it in the `Javascript` tracking code? If so, how?

Thank you.

**Update**

I found a link [here](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2009/07/segment-your-traffic-with-user-defined.html) which goes deeper into *User Defined*. Now I understand its purpose. The problem is the examples in the link talk about setting this variable with the legacy Google Analytics version (ga.js). gtag.js and analytics.js ostensibly employ a different mechanism to set the variable. But it's still unclear how to set this User Defined variable.

Answer (score 0):

Custom variables (and user defined variable) have been replaced with Custom Dimensions and Metrics in analytics.js and gtag.js
[GA Help Center - Custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)